# Time complexity of Maximum independent Set Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, inequality, independent-set

I am learning how to find out  the time complexity of the Maximum Independent Set problem using branch and reduce method. The following is the calculation copied from the textbook.

[image]

Here I am unable to find out how the red box marked line came from it's previous line.**In the previous line also, why is the i subscript absent inside the summation part?**  What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow step by step from the below figure, it should be clear:

[image]